# I am able to connect to Azure SQL Edge with pymssql but not with azuredatastudio what could be the reason?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-edge

So I have this code that is able to print All database names from my `Azure SQL Edge` docker instance.

[image]

On port `1433` there one docker container is running

[image]

I am entering the [image]same credentials on `Azure Data Studio` but I got this error

see this details how I entered for connection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue in my environment with below details:

[image]

I got below error:

[image]

I changed the encryption details to **False**  from **True**.

[image]

It connected successfully without any error.